# Through what to call the method, if I already created constructor with initialization of array of structures?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, structure

I'm trying to call the method `displayChoices`, member of the class `MachineManager` through the object of the class. But I already have a constructor with initializing of the array of structures. How I understood when we create an object of the class compiler implicitly create a default constructor of the class.

Question: How to call method `displayChoices`?

```
#include "MachineManager.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    MachineManager mjp;

    mjp.displayChoices();

    return 0;
}

struct BrewInfo {
    string* DrinkName;
    double* Cost;
    int* Number;
};

class MachineManager {
    static const int Num_Drinks = 3; /// why it works only with static?!!!

    BrewInfo* BrewArr[Num_Drinks];

public:
    MachineManager()
    {
        *BrewArr[0]->Cost = 1.25;
        *BrewArr[0]->Number = 20;

        *BrewArr[1]->DrinkName = "pepsi";
        *BrewArr[1]->Cost = 1.15;
        *BrewArr[1]->Number = 17;

        *BrewArr[2]->DrinkName = "Aloe";
        *BrewArr[2]->Cost = 2.00;
        *BrewArr[2]->Number = 15;
    };

    int displayChoices();
}

int MachineManager::displayChoices() // (which displays a menu of drink names and prices)
{
    cout << 1;
    int choice;
    cout << "|1." << *BrewArr[0]->DrinkName << " |2." << *BrewArr[1]->DrinkName << " |3." << *BrewArr[2]->DrinkName << " |" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    if (!choice || choice == 0) {
        system("slc");
        displayChoices();
    }
    else
        return choice;
}
```

`displayChoices` has to print a menu in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a majo bug in your source code. You do not yet understand, how pointer work.

You are defining an array of pointer with `BrewInfo* BrewArr[Num_Drinks];`.

But these pointers are not initialized. They point to somewhere. Then you are dereferencing  those pointers (pointing to somewhere) and assigning a value to somewhere in the memory.

This is a major bug.

The array dimensions for C-Sytle arrays must be a compile time constant.

You cannot write

```
int x=3;
unt array[x];
```

This is C99 code (called VLA, Variable length array), but not C++.

Solution for you problem:

Do never use C-Style arrays, like `int array[5]`. Use STL container like `std::vector` instead.

Do not use pointers.

This is your major problem. Define your array with `BrewInfo  BrewArr[Num_Drinks];`. Please remove also the pointer from

```
struct BrewInfo {
    string* DrinkName;
    double* Cost;
    int* Number;
};
```